# Suddenly can't install any packages with pip

Tags: pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am on Windows 11 and using Ubuntu 20.04.5 . I recently (3 days ago) updated my Windows, which I think could be related to this problem but also might not be. Specifically, I am suspicious of the update labelled
**Windows Subsystem for Linux WSLg Preview - 1.0.27**
Which I installed 3 days ago.
This is my own personal computer.

Pip: pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

This is my first question and I am mostly just the type of person who wants to use pip and python and not worry about it. So if I forgot important background/version info just tell me how to get it and I will try to add it.

Anytime I try to install a package with pip, I get:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=120)")': /simple/pytorch/
```

Including if I use

```
--default-timeout=1000
```

Then it just waits 1000s of my time instead of 15. My internet speed seems fine for everything else.

Here is what I have tried so far by reading everything I could find after googling the error (nothing changed at all):

- Uninstalling and reinstalling pip
- Disabling IPv6
- Disabling as well as completely uninstalling the VPN i had
- Restarting computer
- Restarting Router (including hard reset)
- Restarting Modem
- Disabling Windows firewall (temporarily just to see if it would fix it, reenabled afterwards).
- Clearing display variable

```
Unset DISPLAY
```

and including in pip install

```
--no-cache-dir
```

Updating things

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

If I try

```
sudo pip install pytorch -vvv
```

Then I get

```
Non-user install because site-packages writeable
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-b2g02nuo
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-5hiikgit
Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-req-tracker-5hiikgit
Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-5hiikgit
Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-5hiikgit
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-j_2ikmsi
1 location(s) to search for versions of pytorch:
* https://pypi.org/simple/pytorch/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/pytorch/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/pytorch/
Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
Getting credentials from keyring for https://pypi.org/simple
Getting credentials from keyring for pypi.org
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/pytorch/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
```

It hangs there until hitting the timeout.

If I try:

```
curl https://pypi.python.org/simple/ -v
```

Then I get

```
*   Trying 151.101.188.223:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to pypi.python.org (151.101.188.223) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Operation timed out after 300157 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300157 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

If I try

```
ping pypi.org
```

Then I get...

```
PING pypi.org (151.101.128.223) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.128.223 (151.101.128.223): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=10.5 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.128.223 (151.101.128.223): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=11.7 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.128.223 (151.101.128.223): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=116 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.128.223 (151.101.128.223): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=11.2 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.128.223 (151.101.128.223): icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=11.8 ms
```

Comment: Which WSL are you using?  You list the WSLg release, but that typically isn't installed separately.  What does `wsl --version` show as the first line?  Thanks!

Comment: In the ubuntu shell there is no command 'wsl'. I can install it though. In windows powershell or command prompt there is no command wsl --version. The closest thing I could find was the list the distribution with --list --verbose, and it says Name = Ubuntu and Version = 2 .

Comment: Sorry, run `wsl --version` from PowerShell, or `wsl.exe --version` in Ubuntu.  Usually best to run the command from PowerShell or CMD, though.  If that just returns help text (or the first line says something like `invalid command`), then that will tell us you have an older version, at least.

Comment: I am getting invalid command for both of those. Rolling back windows to an earlier version indeed resolves the issue. Of course a better fix than that would be appreciated because I would like to be able to update my computer at some point.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - Actually, if you are getting `invalid command`, then you most likely need to make sure that you are fully updated in Windows, then install the WSL *application* from the [Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage).  This is the newest version that will *hopefully* work as intended.  At least, `wsl --version` should then show `1.0.3` (or later).